# Swift - UITableview: How to make a tap on one cell cause change a label in another cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView, and I'd like a tap in cell X to cause the label text in cell Y to change from "Waiting..." to "Done". I'm pretty baffled as to how I should go about this. I've tried to do this using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` , but seemingly I can only modify properties of the cell at the row tapped on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its quite easy to get a cell you need to change, but you have to know which row of your table it is:

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    ...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let row = 7 //or what you set
        let cellWhereIsTheLabel = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) as! MyCell
        cellWhereIsTheLabel.myLabel.text = "Done"

    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: I wrote the code in Swift 3.0, so if you just copypaste the code, you need to update some statements.

Comment: This is what I have gone with - works perfectly. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

A solution will be to update the datasource of your tableview.

When user taps on cell, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called. In this function you can update datasource to provoke changes in other cells and then call `reloadData` to apply changes.

When you call `reloadData` tableView is updated by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This function uses your datasource to update cell.